# Java - Change which method is used through radio buttons

Tags: java, user-interface, fxml, scenebuilder

I am trying to make the radio button selection choose which of the encryption methods is used by the program

```
@FXML
public void atbashChooser(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
public void caesarChooser(ActionEvent evnt) {

}

@FXML
public void encryptShit(ActionEvent event) {
    if (atbashButton.isSelected()){
        encryptField.setText(new AtbashCipher().encrypt(messageField.getText()));
    }
    else if (caesarButton.isSelected()){
        encryptField.setText(new CaesarCipher().encrypt(messageField.getText()));
    }
}

@FXML
public void decryptShit(ActionEvent event) {
    if (atbashButton.isSelected()){
        decryptField.setText(new AtbashCipher().decrypt(messageField.getText()));
    }
    else if (caesarButton.isSelected()){
        decryptField.setText(new CaesarCipher().decrypt(messageField.getText()));
    }
}
```

This does obviously not work, but is there a way to do this in a somewhat easy way? I can share the FXML code as well if this is necessary.

Comment: The atbashChooser and caesarChooser are the radio buttons

Comment: How exactly is this failing?

Comment: It throws a java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at multiplie places

Comment: Can you post the exception text for one of them?

Comment: After being at it for hours it seems there was a simple misspelling in the FXML id.. Thank you for your time anyway